# Unable to Access Remote IBM DB2 From a local PHP Application

Tags: php, db2

I am struggling to connect a remote database IBM DB2 with my PHP application on the local system using xampp.

I am able to connect the db with PgAdmin.

I have added the extensions in the php extension directory and also enabled the php extensions for db2 and odbc both.

I have provided the correct credentials.

This is the error I am getting while connecting.

```
odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect
```

, where as when i connect with php Db2 functions it gives the error function not defined. Please help me in resolving this error.

I am unable to figure out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Why the `websphere` tag? Please also format your question, e.g., error message, and add the actual code.

Comment: please edit your question to add facts (do not use comments, because they are not searchable).  Show the plain text output of `php -v`,  Show the plain text output of `php -info | find /i "thread safety`.  Show the plain text output of `php -m | find /i "ibm"` .  We cannot help unless you write facts clearly in your question.